# Как изменить скорость скролла тачпада в linux ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Всем привет!Недавно решил перейти с win10 на linux ubuntu 23.10, но обнаружил проблему, что скорость скролла тачпада очень высокая. Пересмотрел все форумы на эту тему, но так и не нашел решения.
Как мне кажется, проблема залкючается в том, что linux вообще не видит мой тачпад в системе, но при этом у меня всё работает.

Использую команды по гайдам из интернета.

1)`xinput list` показывает: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Затем использую `xinput list-props 10`, но не могу найти параметр скорости (synaptics scrolling distanse) в списке:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нигде не могу найти решения( Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Надо было просто перейти с *Wayland* на *Xorg*.